TS Decorators: project using experimental definition with or without flag
The following code is working in the TS playground, but doesnt seem to work with the same config settings in my actual project.
Code:
    class Test {
        @loggedMethod
        private async sayHi(txt: string) {
            console.log(txt);
        }
    
        async difMethod() {
            this.sayHi('well');
        }
    }
    
    function loggedMethod(originalMethod: any, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext) {
        const methodName = String(context.name);
    
        function replacementMethod(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
            console.log(`LOG: Entering method '${methodName}'.`);
            const result = originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
            console.log(`LOG: Exiting method '${methodName}'.`);
            return result;
        }
    
        return replacementMethod;
    }
    
    const tClass = new Test();
    tClass.difMethod();

ts.config (local)
 {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "esnext"
        ],
        // "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
      },
      "include": [
        "src"
      ]
    }

On the other hand, the following does work in my actual project
    class Test {
        @loggedMethod
        private async sayHi(txt: string) {
            console.log(txt);
        }
    
        async difMethod() {
            this.sayHi('well');
        }
    }
    
    function loggedMethod(target: any, name: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        target[name] = function replacementMethod(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
            console.log(`LOG: Entering method '${name}'.`);
            const result = descriptor.value?.call(this, ...args);
            console.log(`LOG: Exiting method '${name}'.`);
            return result;
        };
    
        return target[name];
    }
    
    const tClass = new Test();
    tClass.difMethod();

Notice the difference in the arguments for the decorator function. Why the difference? Both are set to TS 5.4.5 and it does work for the second version when I remove the  "experimentalDecorators": true, However, when I do remove  "experimentalDecorators": true, I get an error Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression. The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 3. Which would reflect the documentation of TS5.x decorators as shown https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#decorators in the number of arguments, but it seems that, regardless of my  "experimentalDecorators": true, option, it is using the old decorator definition. Is there another config somewhere?
CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-decorator-issue-rrgmrq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A12%2C4

Maybe there is an inconsistency somewhere in your package.json and package-lock.json leading to an old version being used in your local dev machine. May I ask to have a look at your package.json and/or package-lock.json to see if I can reproduce your problem?

@bblumenwiese I dont think I can share that, but I did go looking. Looks like react-scripts is still reliant on ^4.0, I added an override in package.json for all overrides: { typescript: ^5.4.5 } }. this actually gave me a new warning about esTree not supporting the installed version of TS, which leads me to believe the project is reading TS^5.4.5 now. However, the decorator is still receiving old version args. (EDIT: trashing node_modules and package-log on after the override to be sure things were clean)

Oh no, that's even worse. FYI, react-scripts has not received any updates since 2022: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/ - If you look at their open issues, you will find that people have similar problems as you: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13283
If you are lucky, you could try to find more packages to force-update with overrides like you started to do (next candidate probably being esTree...) but it might not be possible to get it to work at all. People are moving away from react-scripts because nobody seems to be updating it anymore.

yea, I know it wasnt being updated, but this project was started in like 2018. that said, that was the only one I found in our project that wasnt updated to TS 5, and what I did was a project wide override just to see if that worked. I added a codesandbox to the original post that actually demos the issue.

Let me see, so I am trying to access your sandbox but it says I do not have permissions. Could you please double-check its visibility settings?

@bblumenwiese try now
